# Named URL position under fixed menu

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Two pages, one with `<a href='some_url#some_name'>`, and second, on `some_url`, with `<a name='some_name'>`.

So after clicking on URL1, page 2 loads, and URL2 is on the top of the the page.

Now about the problem: this URL2 hidden under `twitter-bootstrap`'s top menu, which have fixed position.

However, when I'm checking named links on Twitter Bootstrap's site, no such problem appears.

I'm tried both Firefox and Opera, it seems no browser dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, when I'm checking named links on Twitter Bootstrap's site, no such problem appears.

I guess you are referring to the link in the navigation span on the left of each page. If you look at the css, specifically the `docs.css` file, which contains the style rules for the documentation website, you'll find out that every section has a `padding` and that's why they don't appear below the navbar.

[image: Twitter Bootstrap documentation website screenshot]

As you can see the section does start hidden by the navbar, but the padding moves the content down so it became visible.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah! Note that you won't get the same result using `margin` ;)

Comment: I'm already have padding-top 60px for body, so body content is hot hidden under navbar. But my links are placed in 'condensed' table, so I can't set padding-top 60px for every link. But thanks for explanation, at least I'm now understand the difference between my links and twitter-bootstrap's sections on their site.